# How to tell TypeScript: to get `keyof importedObject`?

Tags: typescript

My TypeScript v2.2.1, I have list of objects in `my-module`:

```
export const OneObj = { prop1: 'value1' }
export const TwoObj = { prop2: 'value2' }
```

I want to create new type in another module:

```
import * as importedObject from './my-module';

console.log(importedObject)
// { OneObj: { prop1: 'value1' }, TwoObj: { prop2: 'value2' } }}

type NewType = keyof importedObject;
// Error: Cannot find name 'importedObject'
```

Why TypeScript throw error?

> Cannot find name 'importedObject'

And at the same time, I can do this:

```
type NewType = keyof { OneObj: { prop1: 'value1' }, TwoObj: { prop2: 'value2' } };

// NewType === ("OneObj" | "TwoObj")
```

Answer (score 12):

This seems a roundabout way, but I can do this:

```
import * as importedObject from './my-module';

type NewType = keyof typeof importedObject; // OK: "OneObj" | "TwoObj"
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer above no longer works.

```js
import * as importedObject from './my-module';

type NewType = keyof typeof importedObject; // type: never
```

I'm using [v4.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html), but it likely broke in an earlier version. As far as I know, there is no way to achieve this.